# Windows Task Scheduler not working

Tags: windows, authentication, scheduled-tasks, autohotkey, winlogon

I have a script that login on SAP extract some reports. The script must be run at 3 a.m every work day, So I set it to run regularly with the Windows Task Scheduler.

When I was testing it, I've logged in on Windows some time before I've scheduled and the AHK script was "running", but nothing was happening!

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: your script must 1) login to **another** system, 2) do some work, 3) return some result and exit, is that correct?

If that **is** correct:
1) break you script down into the above 3 parts
2) run each part separately with as much logging as you can to check that each stage completes normally and find out where and how it fails if it fails by reading the logs.
3) only proceed to next part of the script when the previous part is working.

Comment: On the log it say`s that the work was successfully done!
But it not works, when I start the task by right click > run it does work, my problem is to run the scrip while the windows is logged off

Comment: Scheduled task was "started or attempted to start" is not the same as the job completed successfully. I would define a successful job as one that **completes ALL tasks**. Winz scheduler defines it slightly differently. That is the reason why I suggested for you to split the script and test and run each part separately. I suspect that it fails to login to remote system because it does not know which user credentials to use, when you run the same task by "right-click" it runs using **your** user credentials by default.